# Configure Spring Integration Aggregator via Java DSL under JDK 7

Tags: spring-integration, java-7, spring-integration-dsl

This my first time to configure Spring Integration via DSL under Java 7. As we know the Lambda expression only works under Java 8. So I refer to the examples [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/spring-integration-java-dsl-reference) and [Spring Integration Java DSL (pre Java 8): Line by line tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/01/spring-integration-java-dsl-pre-java-8-line-by-line-tutorial) to make my configuration as following to collect every 100 messages of same resource to send to remote RESTful service.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow rawDataParsingAndSendingFlow(@Autowired HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpOutboundAdapter,
                                          @Autowired @Qualifier("headerEnricher") HeaderEnricher headerEnricher) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from("rawStringParsingRequestChannel")
                           .transform(new RawStringToCheckDataMessageTransformer())
                           .transform(new DataMessageToDtoTransformer())
                           .aggregate(new Consumer<AggregatorSpec>(){

                                @Override public void accept(AggregatorSpec aggregatorSpec) {
                                    aggregatorSpec.processor(new SimpleMessageGroupProcessor(), null)
                                                  .correlationStrategy(new HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy("resource"))
                                                  .releaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(100))
                                                  .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                                                  .groupTimeoutExpression("60000") ;
                                }
                           })
                           .transform(headerEnricher)
                           .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer())
                           .handle(httpOutboundAdapter)
                           .get();
}
```

However, configuration doesn't work for me and it throws exception as following.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to process message list
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.MethodInvokingMessageListProcessor.process(MethodInvokingMessageListProcessor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor.aggregatePayloads(MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor.java:86)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor.processMessageGroup(AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.AggregatorSpec$MessageGroupProcessorWrapper.processMessageGroup(AggregatorSpec.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:665)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:418)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:358)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:269)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:358)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:269)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:135)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:392)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:477)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:429)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:420)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.sendRawData(Unknown Source)
    at prototype.healthcloud.historic.data.pusher.HistoricDataRetriever$1.extractData(HistoricDataRetriever.java:82)
    at prototype.healthcloud.historic.data.pusher.HistoricDataRetriever$1.extractData(HistoricDataRetriever.java:68)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:697)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
    at prototype.healthcloud.historic.data.pusher.HistoricDataRetriever.retrieveHistoricData(HistoricDataRetriever.java:92)
    at prototype.healthcloud.historic.data.pusher.Application.main(Application.java:119)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Unable to access property 'payload' through getter method
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectivePropertyAccessor$OptimalPropertyAccessor.read(ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:211)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getArguments(MethodReference.java:154)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:71)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:66)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:319)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.MethodInvokingMessageListProcessor.process(MethodInvokingMessageListProcessor.java:73)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectivePropertyAccessor$OptimalPropertyAccessor.read(ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java:636)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid method parameter for payload: was expecting collection.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$ParametersWrapper.getPayload(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:920)
    ... 79 more
```

The root cause is in o.s.i.u.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod method generateExpression, the annotationType is NULL and the parameterType o.s.i.s.MessageGroup is neither sub-interface of `Collection`, `Collection<Message<?>>` or array, so the expression will be set to '#target.processMessageGroup(payload)'. I guess additional logic block have to be added to process MessageGroup type properly (not sure).

Since my aggregation logic is quite simple, I found a work around solution by specifying outputExpression as following.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow rawDataParsingAndSendingFlow(@Autowired HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpOutboundAdapter,
                                          @Autowired @Qualifier("headerEnricher") HeaderEnricher headerEnricher) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from("rawStringParsingRequestChannel")
                           .transform(new RawStringToCheckDataMessageTransformer())
                           .transform(new DataMessageToDtoTransformer())
                           .aggregate(new Consumer<AggregatorSpec>(){

                                @Override public void accept(AggregatorSpec aggregatorSpec) {
                                    aggregatorSpec.outputExpression("#this.![payload]")
                                                  .correlationStrategy(new HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy("resource"))
                                                  .releaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(100))
                                                  .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                                                  .groupTimeoutExpression("60000") ;
                                }
                           })
                           .transform(headerEnricher)
                           .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer())
                           .handle(httpOutboundAdapter)
                           .get();
}
```

So far the work-around solution works for me, but my question is how to configure processor if the aggregation logic is complex.

Comment: The version of Spring Integration is 4.3.10.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aggregatorSpec.processor(new SimpleMessageGroupProcessor(), null)`

You can't use a concrete `MessageGroupProcessor` with that method; it is expecting a POJO bean and method name (which can be null if there's only one eligible method on the bean).

use

`aggregatorSpec.outputProcessor(new SimpleMessageGroupProcessor())`

Note that the output from that processor will be the message group, which is probably not what you want.

You might want to consider using `DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor` (which is the default if you don't provide an `outputProcessor`).

Comment: Neither SimpleMessageGroupProcessor nor DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor without method name works for me and same exception is raised.

Comment: You are right and the POJO aggregator works correct although it looks a bit odd like `public class PayloadExtractingAggregator {@Aggregator public <T extends AbstractDtoBase> List<T> extract(List<T> dtos) {return dots;}}` and DSL is `aggregatorSpec.processor(payloadExtractingAggregator(), "extract")`

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's not very readable; edit the question (or answer) instead. Perhaps you mis-read my answer? When using a concrete `MessageGroupProcessor` the method is `.outputProcessor(...)` instead of `.processor(...)`.

Comment: Sorry for missing your point. Now it's clear to me. Thanks a lot.